# My stylesheet not loading in Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Hi everyone I'm a beginner in `Laravel`, I have a problem in the page `master.blade.php`, i.e., that CSS does not apply and when I open the source and I click on the link `css` it takes me to a HTML page

**This is the source code :** 
[image]

**This is the link of my css :**

[image]

Comment: Can you post a snipet of your custom.css file?

Comment: Is your assets directory inside your public directory?

Comment: What code are you using to load it on the page?

Comment: Can you post your custom.css file?  Could it be an issue with your CSS and not with the link?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all html code tags from your css file (`<!DOCTYPE html>`, `<html>`, `<head>` etc).

See some more information here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Hey [daxro], my style is correct the link opening is not my file css thank you

Comment: @user88057, your `.css` file contents not only CSS, but also HTML.

Comment: Hey ppl, OP knows it is a html page, just read: _...when I open the source and I click on the link css it take me to a html page_

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin when I click on the link in the source file to see if my CSS file the link open this page HTML with content ( Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. ) is like the problem when the routes not working !!

Comment: @user88057 What if you open the file directly from explorer instead of the browser, i.e. by vising the path assets/css/custom.css?

Comment: @Nimesh, the same problem :/

Comment: @user88057 Suggest to make a copy of custom.css and strip the HTML part from the CSS file (keep only the contents present within style tag) and then recheck from browser.

Comment: please someone do on example project with file css and send me it in my gmail => mustaphamouaiad@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

try to do it like this

```
{{ url('css/custom.css'); }}
```

put ur css in the public folder (  public/css/custom.css ) same is for js

Answer (score 0):

Hey everyone thanks for all, i fix my problem it's just in the folder **public** adding another folder **assets** and the style will be in this folder **assets** in the folder **public** not **resources**.

**-like this :**
public/assets/mystyle.css